# Undefined struct name can be used to declare new struct variable

Tags: gcc, struct, declare

I have not define struct `a`, however I can declare variable with struct `a`. The following code can be compiled on Linux by GCC, so , what's the member of struct `a` ? Does `a` is just recognized as `char *` ? I don't know it's meaning.

```
void main() {
    struct a *a1;
    a1 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct a *a1;
```

declares `a1` as a *pointer* to `struct a`. You can legally declare a pointer
to an incomplete `struct` type `a` because the compiler does not need to know the
definition of `struct a` to create a *pointer* to it. All pointers to `struct`
types have the same memory representation and alignment requirements, and that's
all the compiler needs to know to create one. Your assignment:

```
a1 = 0;
```

simply sets the *pointer* to 0, i.e. makes it a null pointer. It presumes nothing
about the type of object that pointer might point to. If instead you were to
attempt something like:

```
a1->member = 0;
```

*that* would require the compiler to have a definition of `struct a` and you
would see a compilation failure like:

```
main.c:3:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct a’
     a1->member = 0;
       ^
```

**Later**

> Where do I need use this syntax? Usually what does undefined struct be used for?

The classic use of incomplete `struct` pointers is to implement an abstract datatype
in C. The C API exposed through a header file is defined in terms of "opaque" `struct` pointers
 - pointers to incomplete types -  so that the client can query
and manipulate objects addressed by these pointers only via the API and cannot
circumvent it to handle the objects in unapproved ways, because they cannot see
the definitions of the datatypes that the opaque pointers point to! Here's an [elementary example
from the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/opaquetypes.html)

Comment: Thanks, where do I need use this syntax? Usually what does undefined struct be used for ?